# Нужен ли выделенный IP адрес для установки SSL сертификата?

Tags: безопасность, ssl

Большинство хостеров предлагает услугу выделенный IP адрес и говорят, что без неё SSL сертификат может некорректно работать. С маркетологической точки зрения их можно понять: лишние продажи не помешают. Я установил сертификат, не имея выделенного IP адреса, и он у меня работает нормально, правда cPanel выдала уведомление, что может быть проблема со старыми версиями IE. Хотелось бы получить от экспертов развёрнутые ответы на следующие вопросы:

1. Наличие выделенного IP адреса обязательно для установки SSL сертификата?
2. Если устанавливать SSL сертификат без выделенного IP адреса, могут ли возникнуть какие-нибудь проблемы?
3. С какими браузерами могут возникнуть проблемы, и какие именно проблемы?

Comment: сертификаты привязанные к IP адресам будут в ближайшее время отозваны, их придется перевыпускать. Больше ни каких привязок к IP. https://www.emaro-ssl.ru/blog/ssl-for-local-domain/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Нет, если конечно это сертификат на домен
2. Могут, но в основном у того кто будет это настраивать, т.е. у хостера. Если адрес не статический надо чтобы ваше доменное имя корректно резолвилось, если на одном адресе несколько сертификатов для разных доменов нужно чтобы веб-сервер поддерживал расширение TLS - Server Name Indication
3. С довольно древними ИЕ6, опера < 8 [список можно посмотреть здесь](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication)

Comment: То есть, по второму пункту, если хостер говорит, что он не может правильно настроить сертификат без выделенного IP, то это говорит о том, что проблемы не у меня, а у него, то есть ему нужно поддерживать TLS - Server Name Indication?

Comment: Скорее всего да, либо им просто лень разбираться / обновлять софт.